# Rails ActiveAdmin Change Collection By Param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm working on a project that has 'users' and 'reviews' activeadmin resources:  In the 'users' tab when you show a user I need to have a link to the specific user's reviews . 
Currently there's a sidebar that links to the reviews

```
#(user.rb)
div do
  link_to "Reviews - #{user.reviews.count}", admin_reviews_path(q: {user_id_eq: user.id})
end
```

But this just leads to the reviews tab and doesn't show the specific user's reviews (the param seems to be meaningless). 
Any advice on how I can change the index method in reviews tab to render a different collection by the param?

```
 #somehow make this action return all reviews that belong to a user if the param is there
 #(reviews.rb)

  index do
  selectable_column
  column :reviewer
  column :product
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
div do
  Review.where(reviews_id: resource).collect do |review|
    link_to User.find_by(user_id_eq: user.id), admin_review_path(Person.find_by(user_id_eq: user.id))
  end
end
```